# Prove $fgh$ has more then $\deg f$ different zeroes

Tags: polynomials

Given $3$ coprime polynomials $f,g,h\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $f+g=h$. Prove that the number of different zeroes of the polynomial $fgh$ is bigger then the $\deg f$. Have no idea about this one.

Comment: I could be totally off, and I'm not terribly experienced in this field, but by the fundamental theorem of algebra, doesn't a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ have $n$-many zeros in $\mathbb{C}$? If that's true, then $deg(fgh)>deg(f)$ and the answer follows from there.

Comment: The zeroes don't have to be different (in the fundamental theorem).

Comment: @menag ah, thanks. Figured I couldn't be right since I didn't use $f+g=h$

Comment: This is known as [Mason-Stothers theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Stothers_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a official solution translated from Serbian

Since $f+g=h$,from $(f,g,h)=1$ we have that $f,g,h$ are coprime in pairs such that the number of different zeroes of $fgh$ is equal to $\deg f-\deg \gcd(f,f')+\deg g-\deg \gcd(g,g')+\deg h-\deg \gcd(h,h')$

(polynomial from $\mathbb{C}[x]$ of degree $n$ has $n$ complex roots; if $k\in\Bbb{N}$ is a multiplicity of a root $\alpha$ of $f$ then $\alpha$ is a root of $f'$ with multiplicity $k-1$)

Let $F=fg'-f'g$ (if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ with multiplicity $k\in \Bbb{N}$,from (f,g)=1 it's not a root of $g$ so it's a zero of $F$ with multiplicity $k-1$ so $F\not= 0$).
Then $F=f(h-f)'-f'(h-f)=fh'-hf'$ and $F=(h-g)g'-(h-g)'g=hg'-h'g$,and because $(f,g,h)=1$,it follows that $\gcd(f,f')\gcd(g,g')\gcd(h,h')\mid F$
it follows $\deg F<\deg g+\deg h$
$$\deg fgh= \deg f+(\deg g+\deg h)-(\gcd(f,f')\gcd(g,g')\gcd(h,h'))\geq \deg f+(\deg g+\deg h)-\deg F>f$$